# iOS 5 and 6 free malloc-ed memory under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, malloc, automatic-ref-counting

How to free dynamically allocated memory in Objective-C under ARC?

By `dynamically` i mean memory allocated with `malloc` to some ivar.

`dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` are no longer being called, at least by my tests.

So when view controller is no longer necessary when and how to start freeing memory?

What i did was to create protocol called `Releasable` (an idea i stole from C#), which has single method `-(void) release`. 
This would be called by some outside proxy when object is no longer necessary.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?  With ARC the memory will become available for allocation as soon as there are no longer any references to it.  There should be no need to manually handle this scenario.

Comment: The `viewDidUnload` routine is not called anymore because iOS no longer releases views automatically on `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Even back in pre-iOS-6-days, `viewDidUnload` was _only_ called when the system had a memory warning. Personally, I'd be inclined to call your `free` calls in the `dealloc` method for your controller. Or, better yet, see if you can avoid `malloc` calls altogether.

Comment: @ZekeTheGeek I am working with OpenGL ES 2.0 and creating vertices. They are plain C structs. As i need speed and space i dont want to pack 50000+ vertices into NSValue's or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dealloc` is still called under ARC. You just don't explicitly call `[super dealloc]`. If `dealloc` isn't being called then something still has a reference to the object instance. Run the analyzer on your project and see what comes up.

`viewDidUnload` is still called under iOS 5 but not under iOS 6.

Adding your protocol and your `release` method are completely unnecessary.

Comment: I have been putting `NSLog`s into `dealloc` and havent seen any being called at the application end. I'll have to check that some more. I'll also run the analyzer.

Comment: +1 @rmaddy - As an aside, I read his comments as representing a misunderstanding when `viewDidUnload` is called in iOS 5. His comments seems to suggest that he thought that this was a general clean up routine when views were dismissed, but as you know, it's not. It was a special purpose routine for when a controller's view was released in low memory situations, but it is not called during standard operations when a view is dismissed/popped.

Comment: @MartinBerger If your `dealloc` routines are not getting called, then you probably have retain cycle (strong reference cycle), such as you can get when you don't `invalidate` a repeating `NSTimer` or if the presenting controller retained (i.e. maintained a strong reference to) the presented controller. But `dealloc` is definitely the right place to do your clean up. You just need to figure out why it's not getting called (if it's not).

Comment: @Rob I have no misunderstanding of when `viewDidUnload` is called. I simply pointed out that it is no longer called under iOS 6. I left the details of when it is actually called under iOS 5 as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: @rmaddy - Yep, understood. I've seen enough of you here on S.O. to know you definitely understand the purpose of `viewDidUnload`. I was just trying to clarify what I interpreted as part of Martin's misconception. I certainly didn't mean to tarnish your good name. :)

Comment: @Rob No problem. I have some turpentine that will take that tarnish right off. :)

Comment: *havent seen any [dealloc methods] being called at the application end*  If you are referring to application termination, it is quite likely that you won't see `dealloc` being called because there is no point to it being called if the app is about to terminate as the system will reclaim all resources anyway.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, the dealloc is being called. As bbum said i wont see them at the end of application launch. And thats where i need everything released. And everything gets cleaned at the end so that's all good. Dealloc is the place then. Thanks.